# Proper Way To Display A Default Image When Replacement Image Is Missing in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code that is used to load user images from a database when their information is displayed.

I was attempting to write it in a way in which it would check if the user already has an image tied to their user id in the database and if so, would leave the image alone and if not, would display a "missing.jpg"/default user image.

I've tried the following, but right now it seems the code is overwriting existing images and replacing them with the missing.jpg image and I don't know why.

I'd appreciate somebody taking a look and showing me why that is.

```
    //Images
    $thisScript = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];
    $dirName = dirname($thisScript);
    $relative_path = "images/headshots/".$this->id.".jpg";
    $missing_path = "images/headshots/missing.jpg";
    $full_path = $dirName . "/" . $relative_path;

    //if(file_exists($relative_path))
    //if(file_exists($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']))
    if(basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) != '' /*and (file_exists($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']))*/)
    {
            $this->process_headshot_file($relative_path, $full_path);
    }
    else
    {
        //$this->process_headshot_file($missing_path, $full_path);
        $query = "UPDATE hraps SET headshot_filename = '".$_SESSION['missing_headshot_image']."' WHERE id = ".$this->id;
        $result = mydb::cxn()->query($query);
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You don't do this on upload; you will typically just check if the file exists on the rendering page (like product.php, check if there are any product images).  If there are no images found, just display the missing image.

Comment: This looks like it's set to check on upload, rather than on display.  More likely, you want to check the DB and see if there's an image defined, and if so, show that image.  Otherwise, show the missing image.  I'd probably skip writing to the DB as well, since there's no point in putting a reference to missing, when the empty DB field does the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement here:

```
 if(basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) != '')
```

is only going to work when there's something in `$_FILES`

Since you say you want to display an image when their information is displayed, that's probably not going to trigger very often, so the `else` is going off instead.

I don't think you need to do anything more complicated than this:

```
$image = "images/headshots/missing.jpg";
if(file_exists($relative_path)) {
    $image = $relative_path;
}

$full_path = $dirName . "/" . $image;
$this->process_headshot_file($image, $full_path);
```

Comment: Using `else { $image = "images/headshots/missing.jpg"; }` does not replace the broken image links with the default missing image.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean you want to add it to their profile if they don't have an image defined already?

Comment: Exactly. I tried: `else { $relative path = "images/headshots/missing.jpg"; $image = $relative_path; }` but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I meant do you want to add it to their database profile? If you just want to display it on the screen, you just need to call `$this->process_headshot_file($image)` (Well, except I'm not sure what the second parameter for that function is supposed to be)

Comment: The second parameter would be fullpath I believe. But yeah, trying to save it to their database profile. Thanks a ton for your help so far by the way.

Comment: Well, in that case, you should just be able to add your existing UPDATE query to an `else`. Though that will update the database every time it can't find another profile picture, which isn't terribly efficient. You could also tweak the SQL where you create accounts so a new profile has the 'missing' image as their default image, which might be a little less work. That way, too, you can be sure that every user will have that field set.

Comment: Hmmmh, I can't get it to work using the `$this->process_headshot_file`, maybe it's because the second parameter is full_path which relies on relative path...Adding the image on user creation sounds like a good idea though.

Comment: I've tweaked my answer a little. I'm a little confused as to why you need a relative link and a full path link to the same file, but all I've done is moved the declaration for `$full_path` down past the point where you've worked out what image to use.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, thanks a lot for your help. My next issue is that `process_headshot_file` is supposedly calling an undefined function...even though it is defined. Argh. Anyway, I'll figure it out. Thanks again Andrewsi.

Comment: Thanks - if you can't work it out, you should add it as a new question and see if someone can figure out why.